# I got the error : Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to register a service worker to a html page and I get the error from title.
I'm working on linux,I have the right to write,delete,modify and so on,(I'm on # ).
I'm on a path like :

```
/var/www/a/b/c/d/e/f/project
```

And here I have a node.js server(index.js) , the html page(index.html) and the service worker(ServiceWorker.js)

The node.js server looks like:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('./mysqldb.js');
const pathView = __dirname + "/views/";
const IMGPath = "/public";
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const listenPort = 8010;

// Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Process application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

// This route will be used to print the type of HTTP request the particular 
Route is referring to
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
next();
});

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/index.html',function(req,res){    
 res.render('/var/www/a/b/c/d/e/f/project/index.html');
});
app.use( "/", router);

// Not found
app.use("*",function(req,res){
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.status(404).send('Page introuvable !');
});

// Run server
app.listen(listenPort, function () {
console.log( listenPort )
});

//HTTPS
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);
```

And the .html file looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('ServiceWorker.js', {
    scope: './'
 }).then(function (registration) {
    var serviceWorker;
    if (registration.installing) {
        serviceWorker = registration.installing;
        document.querySelector('#kind').textContent = 'installing';
    } else if (registration.waiting) {
        serviceWorker = registration.waiting;
        document.querySelector('#kind').textContent = 'waiting';
    } else if (registration.active) {
        serviceWorker = registration.active;
        document.querySelector('#kind').textContent = 'active';
    }
    if (serviceWorker) {
        // logState(serviceWorker.state);
        serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', function (e) {
            // logState(e.target.state);
        });
    }
}).catch (function (error) {
    // Something went wrong during registration. The service-worker.js file
    // might be unavailable or contain a syntax error.
    console.log('Service Worker registration error : ' , error);
});
} else {
    console.log('Please update your brower!');
// The current browser doesn't support service workers.
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I run the index.js node( command : "node index.js")
Everything is fine,the page is loading(I mean the script from the page) and i get the following error:

```
Service Worker registration error :  TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

And I don't know what to do.I basically have the ServiceWorker.js,index.html and index.js in the same folder.I try to run them but somehow the path is wrong...
Can someone help me?

Comment: Use the browser developer mode to assert that what you think is being passed back and forth really is.

Comment: Also it doesn't look like your server setup does anything to handle the `/ServiceWorker.js` path comparable to what it does for `/index.html`.

Comment: Thank you guys for help,I think I'm very close to the answer.I created a /ServiceWorker "page" on node.js just like I did with the index.html in my post code and I set the res.header as "html/javascript" and ran but when I ran it and opened the webpage the followin error showed on my console : cannot find module 'js'.Do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568560/typeerror-failed-to-register-a-serviceworker-a-bad-http-response-code-404-wa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this in your app.js and put your service worker in your public directory/folder.

```
app.get("/ServiceWorker.js", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "ServiceWorker.js"));
});
```